# automapper - how to map object list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, automapper

Let us say my domain object can contain a bunch of objects like this:

```
List<Thing> Things
```

where Thing is defined like this:

```
class Thing
(
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
)
```

My DTO contains

```
List<string> ThingIds;
List<string> ThingNames;
```

The question is how can I use automapper to map Things to the 'relevant bits' in the DTO?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing [custom resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers&referringTitle=Home), i guess.

That's quite unusual requirement - to lose binding between id and name.

---

> I think you are right. sorry I am still learning about the dto/viewmodel mapping. Do you think it is acceptable to put a domain object inside a DTO as there is not much point in creating a dto for Thing?

Do not mix domain model inside view model. You will regret that next week (i did for sure...).

```
class Thing {
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
    public string UnnecessaryProp {get;set;}
}

class ThingViewModel {
    public int ThingId { get; set; }
    public string ThingName { get; set; }
}

class MyView {
    public IEnumerable<ThingViewModel> Things {get;set;}
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362049/defining-view-models-for-mvc-mvp/2362095#2362095) You can find some more thoughts about view model.

Comment: >That's quite unusual requirement - to lose binding between id and name



yeah I think you are right. sorry I am still learning about the dto/viewmodel mapping. Do you think it is acceptable to put a domain object inside a DTO as there is not much point in creating a dto for Thing?