# ASP.NET MVC 2 validation using DTOs instead of domain entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm struggling to mesh two best practices together:

1. Using DataAnnotations + ModelBinding for validation in ASP.NET MVC 2
2. Using DTOs instead of domain entities when passing data via the ViewModel

If I want to pass over DTOs instead of domain entities, then leveraging DataAnnotations + ModelBinding for validation would require me to specify validation attributes on my DTO classes. This results in a lot of duplicated work since multiple DTOs may hold overlapping fields with the same validation restrictions. This means that any time I change a validation rule in my domain, I have to go find all DTOs that correspond with that value and update their validation attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have more than one DTO per entity, so you should only have to apply the validation attributes once per DTO.  If you need multiple entities for a View, include multiple DTO's as properties of your ViewModel.

Comment: That seems a bit restrictive. What if one view needs all the properties of an entity while another view only needs a few? Wouldn't that use case call for multiple DTOs?

Comment: I agree with Kevin, I could think of instances were I would want multiple DTOs for display purposes. However, only having one DTO for submitting data would be a sensible approach.

Comment: DTO's are bags for your data, the ViewModel is the place to mix & match.  I don't think it's a good idea to have multiple DTO's with varying data, that gets into the mess you rightly don't want to have to maintain.

Comment: Right, I understand the need to mix and match DTOs. Where this breaks down, I think, is when your DTOs contain too much information. For example, if you needed to support two views for displaying a single product entity's information, one for admins and one for normal users. The admin view might require a complex DTO that flattens the product and its relationships while the normal user view might only require a basic DTO with far less information. How would you handle that?

Comment: DTO's are storage-independent "flattened" versions of your Model(s).  There should be only one DTO per Entity.  I would not create a DTO that includes both a product and its related Entities.  It is the role of the ViewModel to aggregate related data together to support the needs of a View.

Comment: Fair enough, but what if the admin view needed, say, 100 attributes of a product while a normal view needed only 5 attributes? In that case you have one entity that needs to support two DTOs unless you're willing to deal with the normal view ignoring 95 attributes on the product DTO.

Comment: Assuming a Product is a single Entity, have one DTO support that Entity and make that DTO available as a Product-typed property of the ViewModels for both the admin and normal Views.  Usually, a single Entity is a single row in a database.  If that's not the case, use lazy loading with your favorite ORM to optimize database queries.

Comment: @Dave Swersky I would disagree with beating this drum since there is not rule that DTOs are restricted to flattened data. Having a restriction like this does not make sense in a lot of scenarios.  Let's not access all fields every time you query a few fields from an entity. DTOs are simply containers for transferring data. You can use these DTOs within your ViewModel.

Comment: I recommend not using DTOs as a ViewModel but rather decorate you VM with them, and would use inheritance in your DTOs to organize them per ViewModel. I would also recommend using attributes in your classes rather than on a MetadataType classes since these objects are dumb and refactoring gets more challenging if you separate concerns here.

Answer (score 3):

You might find useful [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362049/defining-view-models-for-mvc-mvp/2362095#2362095).

And keep in mind that validation lives everywhere. There is nothing wrong if DTOs applies UI validation (like getting necessary fields filled, datetime in correct format etc.) and domain objects - domain validation (e.g. account has money before withdrawn operation).

You can't create validation universal. Best thing You can do - put it in appropriate places.

And weed that feeling about duplication out. Usage of DTOs usually means applying single responsibility principle. There is no duplication if you got 2 customer objects where one is responsible for carrying business logic and second that is responsible for displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use meta annotations, which puts the attributes on a separate class:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetaData))]
    public partial class Movie
    {
    }


    public class MovieMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        public object Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(5)]
        public object Director { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Date Released")]
        [Required]
        public object DateReleased { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code sample was borrowed from [this article](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx).

Comment: While, I may be incorrect in saying this, I recommend using Metadata in DTO classes and not outside. as mentioned in my comments above. I would however put them into a metadata type if I was binding directly to my Entity Framework layer on a simple project and/or use the fluent API.